# Why is R producing an extra space at the start of this expression's result?

Tags: r

Why does R produce an extra space at the start of the first expression's result, but there is no such extra space at the start of the second expression's result? I am using R 2.13.1.

```
> 20:30
 [1] 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
> 20:24
[1] 20 21 22 23 24
```

Comment: I don't know but the transition in behavior seems to occur between 28 and 29.

Comment: In general it happens once the vector has >= 10 elements

Comment: @Dason: bug or feature?

Comment: Something is happening here: http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/print.c from line: else { /* .. no dim() .. */

Comment: Possibly someone, somewhere forgot that R is `1`-indexed and C is `0`-indexed and made a harmless typo which got overlooked because it causes no harm?

Comment: OMG `R` is a total FAIL!  Run away!  :-)   Seriously, try 1:50 . It may be deliberate, to get `[1]` tag on the first line of output to be right-justified with `[24]` (or whatever value is the wrap on your console) tag on the second line of output.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft seems correct here. Try `1:1000` and you'll see even more indents in order to match the later lines.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft's got it. (Try typing `1:9; 1:10; 1:99; 1:100; 1:999; 1:1000`) to **see** what's  going on. Seems like Carl's comment should become an official answer.

Comment: By the way,  in general it's not a good idea to post questions  when you're using code that's several years out of date. In this case we could reproduce your work on `R3.0.x` but you really should upgrade your setup if at all possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the encouraging comments,  reposted as an answer.

OMG R is a total FAIL! Run away! :-)

Seriously, try `1:50`  amd then `1:1000` .
 It appears to be deliberate, to get the  `[1]` tag on the first line of output to be right-justified with the `[24]` (or whatever value is the wrap on your console) tag on the second line of output.  Josh O'Brien went further and observed a double-indent when indices went up to 3 digits.